# Is it possible to check previous value of a key in beforeSave?

Tags: parse-platform

Let's say I want to perform custom logic only, say, when a user's `verified` field changes from `false` to `true` (in order to make sure they are allowed to be performing this operation). Is there a way in Cloud Code to see what the 'current', i.e. about-to-be-overwritten value of a field is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at `changedAttributes()`, `previousAttributes()` and `previous("columnName")` to see if these have been exposed in the `beforeSave` handler yet.

**Update note**: none of those methods help.

The only other option I've seen in some older questions is to check `object.existed()` and in that case do a `get()` request to load the original values before the save. Obviously this causes 2 API requests per save.

It would be great to hear back if the changed/previous methods work.

### Update

I have since done some more thorough testing, and the only option is to `get()` the previous version of the record. Nothing else works. This of course requires that you do it in the before-save handler.

Comment: They don't. They return the new value, not the old one.